# wpf ribbon app menu images

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

In the process of updating an app using the 'old' (pre-October 2010 release) ribbon, I am having trouble replicating the xaml below.

```
        <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <r:RibbonApplicationMenu Command="{StaticResource cmdAbout}" >
                <!-- menu items ... >
            </r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

            <ab:CommandReference x:Key="refAbout" Command="{Binding AppAboutCommand}"/>
            <rCmd:RibbonCommandEx x:Key="cmdAbout" DelegatedCommand="{StaticResource refExit}"
                 ... LargeImageSource="{StaticResource imgTimeMachine_32}" 
            />
```

It isn't the command I'm after really, but the image that was part of it (you couldn't directly bind a command, hence the convoluted static resource).

Interestingly, I can set an image property as shown below, but it doesn't actually show the image at all.

```
        <r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <r:RibbonApplicationMenu LargeImageSource="{StaticResource imgTimeMachine_32}">
    ....
```

To compensate, I am using that image for the window icon (don't remember now if the old release supported an icon), but I did like the look of the bigger image more.

Is there a way to show an bigger application image on either the QAT or ApplicationMenu that I am missing?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 1):

Use SmallImageSource instead and try. For me it displays the icon.